# Where can I get the FFProbe JSON schema definition?

Tags: json, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I am using FFProbe to get media file information in JSON format.
I am looking for a complete schema definition for the JSON output option in FFProbe.
See: https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#json

Without the schema I find that different files produce different output, and I have to add more serialization logic by hand as I discover more properties and more tags in the JSON.

Something equivalent to MkvToolNix's full JSON schema definition, but for FFProbe:
See: https://gitlab.com/mbunkus/mkvtoolnix/-/blob/master/doc/json-schema/mkvmerge-identification-output-schema-v12.json

Any ideas if such a schema exists for FFProbe?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one but there is a XML schema which you could try to convert. It's at https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/ffprobe.xsd

Comment: I'm aware of the XML schema. Adding attributes to my JSON parser as I need them seemed like less work and more reliable compared to converting the XSD by hand.